# sublime text 2 console and python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext2

I am able to set python3.2 for the build command in sublime text 2(and build with python3.2), but when invoking the console with <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> the interpreter is mac's default 2.6 version.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Forgot to mention I am on OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 5):

The console in Sublime Text 2 uses the internal version of Python, which is 2.6. There is no way to change it without breaking a whole bunch of stuff. There is a workaround, though. If you just want a Python console within ST2, use the awesome [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) package, which can also be installed through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). Among many other things, you can send selections or whole files to be interpreted through a REPL of your choice, including Python 3. Create `Packages/User/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu` with the following contents:

```json
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"caption": "Python",
                "id": "Python",

                 "children":[
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python 3",
                     "id": "repl_python3",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
                    }
                ]
                }
            ]
            }]
        }
]
```

changing the `"cmd"` option to the **full** path to your `python3` binary. This way your changes will survive any SublimeREPL upgrades. BTW, this path works for any package, so you can feel free to customize away without fear of accidentally losing it all.

Comment: I didn't write `SublimeREPL`, but I use it daily, and the author is really great about getting back to questions or bugs.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is supposed to open Sublime Text's embedded interpreter console, i.e. the one that you use when developing or debugging Sublime plug-ins. You can verify that by noticing that the `sublime` module is available.

If you really want Python 3 console there, upgrade to [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) which embeds Python 3.3. Alternatively, use a dedicated plug-in like [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) (see @MattDMo's answer).

And BTW: If you want a nice environment for interactive Python work, I suggest to disregard the above and give [**IPython Notebook**](http://www.ipython.org) a shot.

Comment: IPython now works in SublimeREPL, at least on Mac. I think he was working on Windows, too, but I don't know if it's functional yet. Don't know about Linux...

Comment: @MattDMo IPython Notebook > IPython. Try it

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the environment variables something similar to the following in Tools > Build System > New Build System

```
{
"path": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
"env":
{
    "PYTHONPATH":"/usr/local/lib/python:/usr/local/username/python/3.2/lib/python3.2/"
},//this comma!
"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

Comment: I tried that, the result is similar to what I had. I get another (working) python3.2 build system, however, the console (cmd&`)still uses python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the Python that comes bundled with Sublime Text.  I wouldn't upgrade it, but if you want to use your own you could do something like:

```
ln -s $HOME/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6 /Your_Sublime_Install_Path/lib/python2.6
```

Comment: that'll break ST2. A lot depends on the exact internal version of python, and since the question is about Python 3, ST2 just plain won't work if you do this.

Comment: Also, ST3 is built on Py3.3, so if you're a registered user (and you **should** be :) you can use that, but in my experience it's still pretty bare at the moment