# Sublime: Change Python version used by plugins

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext2

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong in selecting a different version of Python for Sublime Text 2 (running on Mac)? I want Sublime to use Python 3.2 but not Python 2.6 which is the default version on Mac.

I want Sublime to use Python 3.2 for the plugins I write.

I followed the steps mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342004/trouble-setting-python-version-in-sublime-text2).

This is not working. I know it is not working as I have written a simple plugin to print the version and it prints 2.6.7

My `python.sublime-build`

```js
{
    //Default
    //"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],

    "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3.2", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugins use the internal version of Python that is included with Sublime Text 2, **not** any Python installed on your system.

From the official [Plugin Porting Guide](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/porting_guide.html) for [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) (which is currently in beta):

> Sublime Text 3 uses Python 3.3, while Sublime Text 2 used Python 2.6.

As I detail in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15276533/1426065) to a related question, you cannot change the version of Python, as Sublime will break. So, if you want to write plugins for ST2, you'll have to use Python 2.6. If you simply must use Py3 then you can use ST3.

Your `Python.sublime-build` file is entirely different. It is used for running programs you've written in whichever version (or language) you want. However, it is not for plugins.