# Import python module into SublimeREPL

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

When I try to rub a script in SublimeREPL for Python, it says:

```
ImportError: No module named 'matutil'
```

What setting can I change so the Python REPL is looking in the right directory?

Comment: Is there such a module called `matutil`? There's no record of it on PyPI...

Comment: No, it's just a module I'm using for a class. The module is located in a specific directory, and I want it so when I type "import matutil", the REPL will import the module.

Comment: The answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261193/sublime-text-2-console-and-python-3/15276533#15276533

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058396/python-and-ipython-with-sublimerepl

Comment: Solutions posted in the comments above didn't help in my case. You can find what worked for me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077749/why-sublimerepl-wont-import-a-python-module-or-read-a-file-in-cwd