# Import 3rd party module in SublimeREPL

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

So I am learning to use SublimeREPL, and I encounter a problem.

I have a `main.py` file, and in the same folder a `timer.py`. I write `import` statement in the `main.py`:

```
import timer
```

Then if I open

1) SublimeREPL --> Python --> Python--IPython, and transfer the code to the InteractiveConsole, I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named timer
```

2) SublimeREPL --> Python --> Python, and transfer the code to the REPL console, it runs as expected.

I wonder what is the reason?

Comment: I'm curious about this one too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the sys.path doesn't contain the given directory. You can edit this through the code below

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.getcwd()) 
# os.getcwd() is the current directory, make sure it's the right one.
```

This will make it possible to import timer.py