# Error in Sublime text while using encoding="utf8"

Tags: python, utf-8

I am using this code

with open(title_path, "r", encoding="utf8") as current_file:

in sublime text 3.0

it is showing this error "#encoding="utf8" is giving error
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

without encoding="utf8" the code is running fine.

Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Replace your `utf8` to `utf-8` the problem is you forget to put hyphen between your 8 and utf.

Comment: I tried that too

Comment: [Reading and Writing Unicode Data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)

Comment: It sounds like you are using (in the Sublime Console?) Python2. You can use `io.open` instead of built-in `open`. But really you will want to switch Python 3. If it's the Sublime Console, you have to search the Sublime docs.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261193/sublime-text-2-console-and-python-3) is relevant to you? It's a bit dated (from 2013), but might still help.

Comment: lenz: Yes I am in sublime console and using python 2.7.16

Comment: For Python 2.7: [the **`codecs` module** includes a version of the `open()` function that returns a file-like object that assumes the file’s contents are in a specified encoding…](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)